# Click to turn off volume

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer6

I want to be able to turn on volume by clicking an image which I have worked out but I then want to turn off the volume when the image is clicked off.

I have two images that toggle between speaker on and speaker off

Speaker_on when clicked changes image to speaker off and audio plays
Speaker_off when clicked changes image to speaker on but audio does not turn off

I'm using setVolume to control the audio setttings

Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              //use event delegation
              $(document).on('click','#imageid',function(){

                var $this= $(this);
                $('#toggle').toggle('slide',function(){
                  //swap src of the image on toggle is completed
                 var imgsrc = $this.attr('src');
                  $this.attr('src',$this.data('othersource'));
                  $this.data('othersource',imgsrc);

               });
              });
            });
```

And this is my html

```
<div id="toggle"><strong>Click speaker for volume</strong> </div>

<img src="images/speaker_on.jpg" onclick='jwplayer(smallvid).setVolume(80);'id="imageid" data-othersource="/images/speaker_off.jpg"  />
```

This is the code that I need to call when the speaker off image is selected to the off image

```
 jwplayer(smallvid).setVolume(0);
```

I've tried a couple of approaches but can't seem to get the volume to turn off when I toggle to the speaker off image.

Thanks

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Can't do a jfiddle because the video has to be on a domain, here is the page link I'm working with video on the right. http://www.panic-away-program.com/smallVid32.php

Comment: I see 3 different javascript errors in the console:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined jwplayer.html5.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

The second and the third might be cause by the first one. I don't understand why you have html in a javascript file: http://www.panic-away-program.com/responsive/js/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Try The JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/7b9AT/21/)

```
    jwplayer('playerveGLz8Hc').setup({
        playlist: 'http://jwpsrv.com/feed/veGLz8Hc.rss',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
    var onVol = 100, offVol = 0 ;
    var vol = jwplayer().getVolume();
    if(vol == 0 )
    {
        jwplayer().setVolume(onVol);
        $(this).find('img').toggle();    
    }
    else{
         jwplayer().setVolume(offVol);
        $(this).find('img').toggle();
    }



});
```

I am just toggling between image as you asked and setting volume on and off based on that, please check and let me know if it works

Happy to help